# Font rendering problem after accidentally deleting font folder

Tags: fonts

I accidentally deleted my fonts folder in home/usr/share, then I re-installed dejavu core fonts and ubuntu font family in order to be able to work with my ubuntu again.

Then I started to install other necessary font packages. I around 1 Gb of fonts. but still when I want to use internet many websites like Google, Yahoo mail, Facebook and etc, don't appear to have a nice smooth fonts which they had before.

I either missed some font packages which are important or there is a problem with font rendering which I doubt it.

That would be great if anyone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the steps:**

1. Go to your **home** folder
2. Press **Ctrl+H** or *(Menu -> View -> Show Hidden Files)*
3. Make a backup copy of a file **.fonts.conf** from your **home** folder to any other location
4. Delete the **.fonts.conf** file which is in your **home** folder
5. Restart your browser
6. How are your eyes feeling now!
Done.